# Login system using txt file throws error: localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php, html, authentication

I've got a php login system on my website that I'm developing offline using XAMPP. Every time I try to use the login system I keep getting this error:

localhost redirected you too many times.

I've tried checking around but can't find any help.

Here's my code in index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$userKey = $_POST['userKeySubmitted'];
$keylist = file('priv/keys.txt');

$success = false;
foreach ($keylist as $key) {
    $user_details = explode('|', $user);
    if ($user_details[0] == $userKey) {
        $success = true;
        if ($success) {
            header('Location: user.php');
            $_SESSION['userKey'] = $userKey;
            break;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>

....

<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="userKeySubmitted" class="form-control" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Login</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>




In user.php:

<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userKey'])) {
    $key = $_SESSION['userKey'];
    echo "<h1>Welcome</h1>";
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$user` defined?

Comment: I changed It. It was a mistake, it was supposed to be called $key

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting *before* you set the session value:

```
header('Location: user.php');
$_SESSION['userKey'] = $userKey;
```

Then you check for the value and, if it's not there, redirect back:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userKey'])){
    //...
}
else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
```

Since it wasn't set, this redirects back.  This continues in an infinite loop between the two pages.

Set the value before redirecting:

```
$_SESSION['userKey'] = $userKey;
header('Location: user.php');
```